# regex - shortest repeating subsequence

Tags: regex

I need to find a repeating subsequence in a string of space-delimited integers.

For example, for the string

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 8 9 10 11 12

it would be

> 8 9 10

I came up with this regular expression

> (?<=\s)(\d+(:? \d+(?= ))+) \1+

and it works good until the number of repetitions is more than 4, like here:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 8 9 10 8 9 10 8 9 10 11 12

Now, the first group captures the longest repetition, which is

> 8 9 10 8 9 10

What should I do to keep capturing the shortest one?

Comment: Why are you doing this with regex? This is a very ineffective method.

Comment: Just an annoying comment: what about "1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 3" - the "shortest" sequence "2 3", but that probably isn't what you've meant.

Comment: @Lindrian I know there are algorithms for cycle detection [like these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection) that I could adapt if my string had no repeating values outside of a cycle. But it might have. Could you please point me to other methods for solving this?

Comment: @Kobi Thank you for the comment. It should actually be "1 2 3 2 3", I just don't know how to call it, otherwise I would have changed the confusing title. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Doghouse87 - No, I do not. Naming things is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this pattern:

```
\b(\d+(:? \d+\b)+?)(?: \1)+\b
```

- I changed the lookarounds to `\b`, it should work for you.
- Used non-greedy (lazy) quantifier: `+?` instead of `+`.
- Use `(?: \1)+` instead of `\1+`: you want an additional space for each repetition. You're complaining about four repetitions, but your pattern wouldn't match three (1 2 1 2 1 2).
- Added `\b` at the end to avoid `11 12 11 12999` from matching.

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/FhUoKx44zg

Comment: Looks like if we use *? instead of +?, we can also capture 17 in "14 15 16 17 17 17 17"

Comment: @Doghouse87 - Good point. Of course, every little change in the semantics of the question requires a different pattern.

Comment: This pattern won't match repeating *non-contiguous* subsequences, like *8 9 10* in *1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 10 8 9 10 11 12*.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - right, that wasn't required here, and in that case regex probably wouldn't help. If that's what you need, please ask a new question.